# emacs で、スペース区切りのカラムをいい感じにフォーマットしたい

Tags: emacs, elisp

たとえば、以下は rails の migration コードです。

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title, comment: 'タイトル'
      t.text :body, comment: '本文'
      t.integer :user_id, comment: 'ユーザーID'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

しかし、これではコードが読みにくいので、できることなら以下の様に整形したいと思いました。

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string  :title,   comment: 'タイトル'
      t.text    :body,    comment: '本文'
      t.integer :user_id, comment: 'ユーザーID'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

しかし、このようなスペースを挿入していく作業は、手で毎回行うにはちょっと辛すぎるかな、と思いました。

## 質問

上記のような、スペース区切りで、縦に揃えたいコードの行たちがあったときに、これをうまく整形する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0):

`M-x align-regex` で整形する方法があるようです。

質問の内容だと`:title`や`:body`にあたる列の指定が少し面倒そうですが。

参考:
[emacs でソースコードを整形する方法](http://pyopyopyo.hatenablog.com/entry/20061228/p1)

> M-x align-regex を使うと，指定した単語(厳密には正規表現)でテキストを整列できます．
>   たとえば，変数名 msg で整列したい場合は，M-x align-regex して，"msg" と入力します．
>
> ```
> const char* foo(int code) {
>     const char *msg = NULL;
>     switch (code) {
>     case LS_SUCCESS:    msg = "success";break;
>     case LS_NO_RECORD:  msg = "no record";break;
>     case LS_NO_TOKEN:   msg = "no token";break;
>     }
>     return msg;
> }
> ```